# Swipe to go back in navigation controller on iOS 7

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7

I've been looking through the iOS 7 / UIKIT framework, and although it looks quite different aesthetically it's really the same SDK underneath from what I can see.

My question, is there any extra code that needs to be included to get the draggable behaviour between pushed tableviews/views?

When you push a view onto a UINavigationController you can now drag back to the previous controller from the side rather than pressing the back button.

This behavior can be seen in mail.

How is this achieved, do I need to add any code to add it to my app?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `UITableView` or `UITableViewController`, but with `UINavigationController`. And yes, you get this behavior for free as long as the back button is visible.

Comment: Thanks all for the input

Comment: Any idea on how to get this behavior if the back button is not visible?

Comment: @PauloCesar: There is a new gesture recognizer UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer. Create an instance of it and add it to your view.

Comment: If I do not want this behavior in my app. How can I stop it?

Comment: @optme: That should really be a separate question, but `UINavigationController` has a property `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` that you can probably work with. See also https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/interactivePopGestureRecognizer

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets I've added the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to my view, but this isn't enough. Any idea as to what I need to do in order to get this functionality without the back button showing in the top bar of my navigation controller?

Comment: @Arcrammer: You should ask a separate question for that. Be sure to search around first, I'm sure this has been asked before.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Actually there's a hack I've found that gives you this functionality. You set the navigation controllers' gesture recogniser delegate to nil and it magically works (for me, as of Xcode 7 and iOS 9.0.2. `self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil`

Comment: @Arcrammer nice - thanks for the tip, worked like a charm!